# Geometric constraint in between two joints

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

does there already exist a possibility to couple two joints by a geometric constraint like a chain drive, e.g. setting the same angle? If yes, how can I access it?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1091/geometric-constraint-in-between-two-joints/) by [anbe](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/178/anbe/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-01-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There currently is nothing like a chain drive in gazebo. Feel free to contribute, or file a ticket for this feature on bitbucket.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0